# Why does hybridization produce a more stable configuration?

Tags: orbitals, hybridization

My text, and the other sources I've checked, include information on the effects, and kinds, of hybridized orbitals; however, they do not explain what properties of hybridized bonds conduce greater stability.

Why does hybridization produce a (lower energy) more stable configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What causes orbital hybridization?

Hybridization only occurs in response to bond formation, that is an atom will not just spontaneously hybridize on its own.  Further, **an atom will only hybridize if hybridization leads to the formation of a more stable (lower energy) molecule**.

Nature is very efficient at exploring the energy surface and finding whatever energy minimum is available.  For example, ammonia ($\ce{NH3}$) is roughly a tetrahedron with $\ce{H-N-H}$ bond angles around 109.5° (the tetrahedral angle) using (roughly) $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized orbitals. For ammonia, mixing (hybridizing) it's $\mathrm{2s}$ and three $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals to form four $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized orbitals that are used to form three $\ce{N-H}$ bonds and one lone pair orbital produces a more stable molecule than if it were not hybridized.  On the other hand, the analogue phosphine ($\ce{PH3}$) chooses to remain roughly unhybridized, using p-orbitals to form its $\ce{P-H}$ bonds with a resultant $\ce{H-P-H}$ bond angle around 90°.  Bond strengths, steric factors, etc. all play into determining whether a hybridized or unhybridized structure will be the more stable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear in my question. I (unjustifiably) presumed readers would regard the disposition of atoms to configure themselves most stably as common knowledge. I've edited my question.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer, hybridization does **not** always produce a more stable configuration - some atoms, when they combine to form a bond, do not hybridize ($\ce{PH3}$).

Comment: Whichever configuration (hybridized or unhybridized) has the strongest bonds, the smallest steric repulsion, etc. (*e.g.* the lowest energy) is the configuration that will be adopted.

Comment: In sp2 configuration does the repulsion occurs between hybridized and unhybridized orbitals @ron too ?

Comment: Or just the repulsion is considered between the three hybridized orbitals and hence thats the reason bond angles are 120° otherwise it could be less if considered the unhybridized orbital too ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax  Repulsion occurs between all orbitals, hybridized and unhybridized, that contain electrons.  The repulsions are minimized when the molecule attains the lowest energy geometry possible.